# Terraform Config for invoking SES as destination from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-ses

I'm trying to get Lambda to send emails from SES through Terraform "aws_lambda_function_event_invoke_config" resource.

Here's the config:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function_event_invoke_config" "send-email" {
 function_name = aws_lambda_function.send-email.function_name

   destination_config {
     on_success {
       destination = aws_ses_?????
     }
   }
}
```

I'm not able to figure out what SES resource would be referenced here, for Lambda to correctly invoke SES to send emails.

Comment: Well, have you defined any SES configuration anywhere?

Comment: Yes. I've created 5 SES resources:
"aws_ses_domain_identity", "aws_ses_domain_identity_verification", "aws_ses_domain_dkim", "aws_ses_configuration_set", "aws_ses_domain_mail_from". I'm not sure which one of these the lambda will target.

Comment: Well, what is Lambda supposed to do?

Comment: I want Lambda to send email through SES. Lambda code is given in my original post.

Comment: No one out there?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, I don't know which SES you want to use to send the emails to. There are a lot of details missing. The easy answer would be to tell you it's an SES ARN, but I don't know which one.

Comment: Btw, I forgot, you cannot use SES for the destination. Here is a list of destinations: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-async-destinations.

Comment: Thank you Marko. I had this figured out yesterday. Valid Lambda destinations indeed do not include SES.